# Оптимизация таблицы друзей

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, индексы

Есть таблица users с индексом id. Необходимо реализовать возможность пользователям добавлять друг друга в закладки. Можно ли использовать следующую таблицу, если ее ожидаемый размер до 100млн. строк? Есть ли более производительный способ решить эту задачу?

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `user1` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user2` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: А какими запросами будите пользоваться для получения из нее данных?

Comment: Чаще всего нужно будет получать список друзей заданного пользователя.

Comment: Значит по этому столбцу (по которому условие будет) нужно создать индекс.

Comment: Есть способ оптимизировать вашу схему БД. Вообще убрать эту таблицу и хранить друзей в поле у пользователя(это в целом называется де-нормализация). НО! Это естественно ограничит варианты запросов, который можно выполнить с друзьями.

Comment: Это единственный вариант? Как справляются с такой нагрузкой социальные сети? Существует ли более производительный способ узнать, является ли $user1 подписчиком $user2, чем следующий: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM friends WHERE user1=$user1 AND user2=$user2 ?